# GMM/EM on time series cluster

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, cluster-analysis, gmm, expectation-maximization

According to a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSG.2015.2409786), it is supposed to work.
But as a learner of scikit-learn package.. I do not see how.
All the sample codes cluster by ellipses or circles as [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html).

I would really like to know how to cluster the following plot by different patterns... 0 -3 are the mean of power over certain time periods (divided into 4) while 4, 5, 6 each correspond to standard deviation of the year, variance in weekday/weekend, variance in winter/summer. So the ylabel does not necessarily meet with 4,5,6.
[image]

Following the sample..BIC did generate that the optimal number of clusters is 5.

```
n_components = np.arange(1, 21)
models = [GMM(n, covariance_type='full', random_state=0).fit(input)
      for n in n_components]
plt.plot(n_comp, [m.bic(read) for m in models], label = 'BIC')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('n_components')
```

[image]

If I plot with the sample code available however.. it returns something completely weird, not worth sharing. I though negative BIC was ok. But I don't even know if it clustered correctly to deduce that 5 is the optimal number.

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't look at the paper. There is no clear definition of correct cluster so you have to decide whether a particular clustering is okay. If the result is not good intuitively, I would suggest to use other clustering methods to see if something changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in an effort to close this question..my following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298542/scikit-learn-gmm-issue-with-return-from-means-attribute) answers how to cluster using GMM.

Create a model using the parameters accordingly

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=10, covariance_type ='full', \
              init_params = 'random', max_iter = 100, random_state=0)
```

Fit your data (number of samples x number of attributes) whose name is input in my case

```
gmm.fit(input)
print(gmm.means_.round(2))
cluster = gmm.predict(input)
```

Cluster contains the labels to each of these samples of my input

Feel free to add, if I've gotten anything wrong

Comment: hi, I was wondering if you could have a look at a similar problem in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414169/how-can-implement-em-gmm-in-python)
Thanks in advance.